# using ag in emacs under macos

Tags: macos, emacs, ag

I use project-root to setup root directory of the project as:

```
(setq project-roots
       `(("Git Project"
          :root-contains-files (".gitignore"))))
```

Then I go into my git project directory (e.g ~/.emacs.d), and press `M-x ag-project-files` and enter some search string. It shows the files which contains the string. But when I push enter key on top of the file (in order to jump into that file), it shows error message like:

> Find this error in (default File: lisp/ag.el): ~/.emacs.d/

I don't know how this error come out? It is all right when I use emacs in Linux, but no good in Mac. Have you ever met this problem?

Comment: I do not know what's wrong with `ag.el` but, I use `counsel` package which comes built in with the command `counsel-ag` which works fine in macOS. I had tested `ag.el` too and it worked just as fine.
Also, if you use projectile, you might want to try `projectile-ag` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem using projectile-ag. It turned out that setting the "--nogroup" parameter for ag was causing this break (but only on macOS). To work around this I just set ag-arguments to not include the "--nogroup" param:

```
(setq ag-arguments (list "--smart-case" "--column"))
```

Comment: Glad I could help @ruanhao. This same problem hurt me quite badly. If you like the answer feel free to vote it up. Cheers.